# В PHP перевести из числа в дату

Tags: php, дата, int

При смывании форматирования с листа MS Excel даты превратились в числа. Примеры:

20.07.2018 => 43301

17.08.2018 => 43329

03.10.2018 => 43376

04.10.2018 => 43377

Как теперь средствами PHP преобразовать эти числа обратно в даты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл следующий способ преобразования:

```
$date = new DateTime("1899-12-30");
$date->modify("+".$date_in_number_format." day");
```